# Disable mouseout event on mouseclick in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, events

I am working in wordpress with a jquery file. I have three events in jquery code mouseover, mouseout and click function. I want to disable mouseout event on click event because mouseout event disturbs the programming of click event as after click I remove my cursor away the mouseout event changes my image button. I want to disable mouseout event if click event fires.

Below is my code

Mouseover Code

```
$(document).on("mouseover","#star5", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).attr('src','http://localhost:8080/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/checkmark-small-filled.png');
    var aidd = $(this).closest("form").find("#star5");
    $(aidd).prevAll(".star").attr('src','http://localhost:8080/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/checkmark-small-filled.png');
    //global=1;

});
```

Mouseout Function

```
$(document).on("mouseout","#star5", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).attr('src','http://localhost:8080/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/checkmark-small-unfilled.png');
    var aidd = $(this).closest("form").find("#star5");
    $(aidd).prevAll(".star").attr('src','http://localhost:8080/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/checkmark-small-unfilled.png');
    //global=1;

});
```

Click Function

```
$(document).on("click",".star", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var myclickvalue= jQuery(this).val();
    if (myclickvalue = 5)
    {
        $(myclickvalue).attr('src','http://localhost:8080/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/checkmark-small-filled.png');
        var aidd = $(this).closest("form").find("#star5");
        $(aidd).prevAll(".star").attr('src','http://localhost:8080/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/checkmark-small-filled.png');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `off`:

> Remove an event handler.

```
$('selector').off('event');
```

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: Tushar I have used this but the mouseout event does not disable on click     $('.star').off('mouseout');

Comment: try $(document).off('mouseout', '.star');

Comment: no it is not working here is my code now $(document).on("click",".star", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); $(document).off('mouseout','.star');
    var myclickvalue= jQuery(this).val();
    if (myclickvalue = 5)
    {
        $(myclickvalue).attr('src','http://localhost:8080/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/checkmark-small-filled.png');
        var aidd = $(this).closest("form").find("#star5");
        $(aidd).prevAll(".star").attr('src','http://localhost:8080/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/checkmark-small-filled.png');
    }
});